# Accessing Yahoo Weather API through Flash and Oauth 2.0

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, oauth-2.0, yahoo-weather-api

I am trying to access weather API through flash.However, stuck on the last step, of getting values from the API in exchange of access token.The problem is that the access token must be passed through authorization header, and Flash has no way to send the authorization header.That is, it doesnot allow it for security reasons.Is their any solution available for this problem ?

Reference : 
https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/apirequests/

It says :

> Making API Requests ¶ To make API requests, include the access token
>   in the Authorization header. Note that API requests must be made
>   securely over HTTPS. The header content comprises of the word Bearer
>   followed by the access token. Sample Request Header ¶
>
> GET https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/abcdef123/profile?format=json
>   Authorization: Bearer [place your access token here]

Here is the code I am using :

```
var url = "http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2444293&u=f"
var access_token = < access token here >
var encoder: Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
encoder.insertNewLines = false;
encoder.encode(access_token);
var urlRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest("./proxyForYahoo.php");

var urlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onHTTPStatus);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
urlRequest.contentType = "application/json";

urlRequest.requestHeaders = new Array(
    new URLRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + encoder.toString()),
    new URLRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json'),
    new URLRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

);
var urlVars: URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.data = url;
urlRequest.data = urlVars;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);


function onComplete(e: Event): void {
    trace("completed---");
    trace(e.target.data);
}
function onHTTPStatus(e: Event): void {
    trace("onHTTPStatus");
    trace(e.target.data);
}
function onIOError(e: Event): void {
    trace("onIOError");

}
function onSecurityError(e: Event): void {
    trace("onSecurityError");

}
```

Yahoo proxy :

```
<?php

$url = $_REQUEST['data'] ;  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

ob_start();

curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$string = ob_get_contents();

$content = ob_end_clean();

echo $string;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reading see : https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#get-started=

Below is an example AS3 code for getting Yahoo Weather data without involving Oauth tokens.

Here you would only need a PHP proxy if your SWF is running from non-HTTPS web location. In such a case, just write a PHP version of that `getYahooWeather` function where it **echo**'s back the `str_YahooResponse` to any requesting loaders..

**Test** : Simply update `str_Woeid = "2444293";` and test compile.

```
var str_Woeid : String = "";
var str_YahooRequest : String = "";
var str_YahooResponse : String = "";

var Weather_Loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

//# get Yahoo response into : str_YahooResponse : via function
str_Woeid = "2444293"; //# the WOEID of Weather request
getYahooWeather(str_Woeid, "json"); //# choose : "xml" OR "json" 

function getYahooWeather( inputStr : String, fmt : String = null  ) : void
{
    if (fmt == "xml") { fmt = "format=xml" }
    else { fmt = "format=json" }

    str_YahooRequest = ("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" 
                        + fmt //either: =json OR =xml
                        + "&q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.forecast%20WHERE%20u=%27"
                        + "f" //temperature fomat : f = farenheit, c = celsius
                        + "%27%20AND%20woeid%20=%20%27"
                        + inputStr //the WOEID
                        + "%27");

    Weather_Loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    Weather_Loader.load(new URLRequest(str_YahooRequest));
}

function onLoaded(evt:Event) : void 
{
    //# put weather data to string (then parse as JSON or XML)
    str_YahooResponse = evt.target.data;
    trace("Yahoo Weather Data ::::::::: " + str_YahooResponse);
}
```

Now you can use the updated string `str_YahooResponse` with relevant parser...
for example as : `myJSON.parse(str_YahooResponse);`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked it as solved for now, unless someone answers with the solution for tokens.  :)

Comment: Is there any **specific** reason you want to involve tokens? Because Yahoo themselves created the above system for making weather requests without needing such extras like a Developer account or tokens or proxies etc... In short, it just works!!. PS: With my shown code it's enough to say `getYahooWeather("2444293");` for a result. If you want it in xml then specify as `("2444293", "xml");` or simply change that `fmt` in **else** statement to default to xml when specification string is `null` (ie: not specified)...

Comment: Tokens are actually too common nowadays. For example flash work fine with the yahoo's flickr api. Also good with twitter api. So, was just curious what's the way to make it work with weather api.